# Django 2.2.9 - unexpected results from timedelta()

Tags: django, python-3.x, datetime

Please forgive me if this has already been asked
I am following a course online, albeit 3 years old, so somethings have been updated since then
However datetime seems to be roughly the same from what I can see.

The problem arises when we use timedelta to filter all the sales in the last month
I have added some test sales over the weeks and when I tried to filter it down to the last 48 hours, nothing
with a bit of testing i went back 12 days (as of this question and a list of items sold back on the 20th February showed up but nothing sooner.
I went into the admin and updated one of them and refreshed the page. and it disappeared completely 
Can anyone provide any insight as to what i am missing?
If you need more information please say:

Models.py

```
from decimal import Decimal
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Count, Sum, Avg
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone

from addresses.models import Address
from billing.models import BillingProfile
from carts.models import Cart
from ecommerce.utils import unique_order_id_generator
from products.models import Product

ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('created', 'Created'),
    ('paid', 'Paid'),
    ('shipped', 'Shipped'),
    ('refunded', 'Refunded'),
)

class OrderManagerQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def recent(self):
        return self.order_by("-updated", "-timestamp")

    def by_date(self):
        now = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=12)
        return self.filter(updated__day__gte=now.day)

    def totals_data(self):
        return self.aggregate(Sum("total"), Avg("total"))

    def cart_data(self):
        return self.aggregate(Sum("cart__products__price"), Avg("cart__products__price"), Count("cart__products"))

    def by_status(self, status="shipped"):
        return self.filter(status=status)

    def not_refunded(self):
        return self.exclude(status='refunded')

    def by_request(self, request):
        billing_profile, created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
        return self.filter(billing_profile=billing_profile,)

    def not_created(self):
        return self.exclude(status='created')

class OrderManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return OrderManagerQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def by_request(self, request):
        return self.get_queryset().by_request(request)

    def new_or_get(self, billing_profile, cart_obj):
        created = False
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(
            billing_profile=billing_profile,
            cart=cart_obj,
            active=True,
            status='created'
        )

        if qs.count() == 1:
            obj = qs.first()
        else:
            obj = self.model.objects.create(
                billing_profile=billing_profile,
                cart=cart_obj
            )
            created = True
        return  obj, created

class Order(models.Model):
    billing_profile     = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_id            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    shipping_address    = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="shipping_address", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billing_address     = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="billing_address", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart                = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status              = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='created', choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES)
    shipping_total      = models.DecimalField(default=5.99, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    total               = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    updated             = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id


    objects = OrderManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp', '-updated']

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("orders:detail", kwargs={'order_id': self.order_id})

    def get_status(self):
        if self.status == "refunded":
            return "Refunded order"
        elif self.status == "shipped":
            return "Shipped"
        return "Shipping Soon"

    def update_total(self):
        cart_total = self.cart.total
        shipping_total = self.shipping_total
        new_total = Decimal(cart_total)+Decimal(shipping_total)
        formatted_total = format(new_total, '.2f')
        print(type(new_total))
        self.total = formatted_total
        self.save()
        return new_total


    def check_done(self):
        shipping_address_required = not self.cart.is_digital
        shipping_done = False

        if shipping_address_required and self.shipping_address:
            shipping_done = True
        elif shipping_address_required and not self.shipping_address:
            shipping_done = False
        else:
            shipping_done = True


        billing_profile = self.billing_profile
        billing_address = self.billing_address
        total = self.total
        if billing_profile and shipping_done and billing_address and total > 0:
            return True
        return False

    def update_purchases(self):
        for p in self.cart.products.all():
            obj, create = ProductPurchase.objects.get_or_create(
                order_id = self.order_id,
                product = p,
                billing_profile= self.billing_profile,
            )
        return ProductPurchase.objects.filter(order_id = self.order_id).count()

    def mark_paid(self):
        if self.status != 'paid':            
            if self.check_done():
                self.status = "paid"
                self.save()
                self.update_purchases()
        return self.status


def pre_save_create_order_id(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.order_id:
        instance.order_id = unique_order_id_generator(instance)

    qs= Order.objects.filter(cart=instance.cart).exclude(billing_profile=instance.billing_profile)
    if qs.exists():
        qs.update(active=False)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_create_order_id, sender=Order)


def post_save_cart_total(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        cart_obj = instance
        cart_total = cart_obj.total
        cart_id = cart_obj.id
        qs = Order.objects.filter(cart__id=cart_id)
        if qs.count() ==1:
            order_obj = qs.first()
            order_obj.update_total()

post_save.connect(post_save_cart_total,sender=Cart)

def post_save_order(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    print("running")
    if created:
        print("updating...first")
        instance.update_total()

post_save.connect(post_save_order,sender=Order)

class ProductPurchaseQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(refunded=False)

    def digital(self):
        return self.filter(product__is_digital=True)

    def by_request(self, request):
        billing_profile, created = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
        return self.filter(billing_profile=billing_profile,)


class ProductPurchaseManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductPurchaseQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def all(self):
        return self.get_queryset().active()

    def digital(self):
        return self.get_queryset().active().digital()       

    def by_request(self, request):
        return self.get_queryset().by_request(request)

    def products_by_id(self, request):
        qs = self.by_request(request).digital()
        ids_ = [x.product.id for x in qs]
        return ids_

    def products_by_request(self, request):
        ids_ = self.products_by_id(request)
        product_qs = Product.objects.filter(id__in=ids_).distinct()
        return product_qs

class ProductPurchase(models.Model):
    order_id        = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    billing_profile = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # billingprofile.productpurchase_set.all()
    product         = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # product.productpurchase_set.count()
    refunded        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    updated         = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ProductPurchaseManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

Views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.db.models import Count, Sum, Avg
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render

from orders.models import Order

class SalesView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'analytics/sales.html'

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        if not user.is_staff:
            return render(self.request, "401.html", {})
        return super(SalesView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SalesView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        qs = Order.objects.all().by_date()
        context['orders'] = qs
        context['recent_orders'] = qs.recent().not_refunded()
        context['recent_orders_data'] = context['recent_orders'].totals_data()

        context['recent_orders_cart_data'] = context['recent_orders'].cart_data()

        context['shipped_orders'] = qs.recent().not_refunded().by_status("shipped")
        context['shipped_orders_data'] = context['shipped_orders'].totals_data()

        context['paid_orders'] = qs.recent().not_refunded().by_status("paid")
        context['paid_orders_total'] = context['paid_orders'].totals_data()
        return context
```

Sales.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content%}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1>Sales Data</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">    
    <div class="col">
      <p>Recent Toal: £{% if recent_orders_data.total__sum %} {{ recent_orders_data.total__sum }}{% else %}0 {% endif %}</p>
      <ol>
        {% for order in recent_orders %}
        <li>{{ order.order_id}}
        {{ order.total}}
        {{ order.updated}} </li>    
        {% endfor %}
      </ol>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <p>Shipped Total: £{% if shipped_orders_data.total__sum %}{{ shipped_orders_data.total__sum }}{% else %}0{% endif %}</p>
      <ol>
        {% for order in shipped_orders %}
        <li>{{ order.order_id}}
        {{ order.total}}
        {{ order.updated}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <p>Paid Totals: £{% if shipped_orders_data.total__sum %}{{ paid_orders_total.total__sum }}{% else %}0{% endif %}</p>
      <ol>
        {% for order in paid_orders %}
        <li>{{ order.order_id}}
        {{ order.total}}
        {{ order.updated}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work fine:

```
now = timezone.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(days=12)
return self.filter(updated__date__gte=now)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your filter by_date method you are using a filter on the day not the date. This won't help as it'll return the day of the month. So if the date was 2020-03-11 it would return 29 for now.day.  If you change .day for .date() as well as updated__day__gte for updated__date__gte it should be okay

```
def by_date(self):
        now = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=12)
        return self.filter(updated__date__gte=now.date())
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however I am getting an error: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Sorry about that I msised the brackets in .date as its a method. You want this 

``` return self.filter(updated__date__gte=now.date())```

I've updated my reply to make it clearer.